# the application that opened from "Run" method has Resolution problem

Tags: autohotkey

```
;quick launch
RCtrl::Run D:\Program Files\Notion\Notion.exe
```

i notice that Run doesn't have parameters to adjust .
This is the effect produced in Notion , and other applications are same
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ApHIX.png)

Answer (score 0):

You shoud use quotation marks just in case because program files folder has a space.
Maximized run code looks like this:

RCtrl::Run "D:\Program Files\Notion\Notion.exe",,Max

AHK Run function documentation found here:
https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Run.htm